# What does "ever too X" expression mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> It is worth noting that the section of the wire coming from the
> positive terminal of the battery to the first fuse is
> effectively unprotected. If this was **ever too short**, it could cause an
> electrical fire. For this reason, you should fit the first fuse for
> each electric circuit as close to the battery/power source as
> possible.

How I understand the second phase: if wire is too short, it could cause a fire.

How I understood the third phrase: we must make this wire as short as possible for safety reasons.

Either there is a mistake in the text, or I don't get the meaning of the expression.

Comment: It's the same as "Have you _ever_ (at any time in your life) been to France?" If that section of wire was _ever_ (in any circuit of this type) too short...

Comment: @KateBunting: Nah - it's just a typo (should be infinitive marker ***to***, not ***too = excessive***). But thinking about it, I'd guess one likely reason a wire might ***short** [out]* could be because it's ***too long***.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Of course - I hadn't thought of _short_ being a verb.

Comment: If the section of wire were ever to short circuit. **To short= to short circuit**.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Nothing to do with length. The quoted text is from an article on a camper van website. It contains an error. The correct text would be:

> However, it is worth noting that the section of the wire coming from
> the positive terminal of the battery to the first fuse (or fuse box)
> is effectively unprotected. If this was ever **to** short, it could
> cause an electrical fire.

If a wire 'shorts' it touches another wire or conductor causing a short circuit.

Really, I would write "If this **were** ever to short", using the subjunctive, but many people nowadays don't bother. Don't expect good English on camper van sites.

Comment: I'd expand that last point: "Don't expect good English anywhere" When I read my town newspaper I notice typos and grammatical mistakes almost every week.

Comment: I hardly expected that the text might have such a funny typo. Thank you a lot! Hahaha

Comment: Good answer. I’d also note that in this usage, “short” is an abbreviation of “short OUT’, which is the specific wording for an accidental completion of an electrical circuit without resistance, causing failure.

Comment: @ChrisMelville - or an abbreviation of "short-circuit", if you like but it doesn't have to be an abbreviation of anything.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey - “Short circuit” is the noun phrase. ‘Short out” is the verb phrase; and here it’s being used as a verb :)

Comment: Fire brigade called to pub after e-cigarette set woman's clothes on fire: "The battery was short-circuited by some loose change in her pocket" - Bournemouth Echo 2 April 2019

Comment: Look up "short circuited by" on Google and tell me it's not a verb phrase.

Comment: I'd be inclined to do so, too.  But this might be hypercorrection.  The past subjunctive is for counterfactuals, which this is not.  It's predictive.

Comment: I would call it speculative - If my aunt were sixty-five, she could get a discount air fare.

Comment: It may be worth noting that it **is** plausible to correctly write a sentence that says “If this was ever too short, it could cause an electrical fire,” if the “this”/“it” in question were something that could have a length or duration and that there was some minimum length or duration necessary to avoid an electrical fire.

Comment: Speaking as a former electrician and electronics technician, I cannot think of such a situation.

Answer (score 1):

*Ever so* can be used in place of *very". A princess might say "this cake is ever so delicious" or "thank you ever so much". *Ever too* isn't quite right, but sounds enough like *ever so* to be acceptable. "Your hair is ever too short, how will I braid it?" is clearly using "ever too" as as awkward *very*. It can be tricky (for a non-native speaker) to tell them apart. "If you're ever so rude to me again" (speaking of the future) vs. "Lord Paisley, you're ever so rude to me" (means *very*, speaking of the present and past). Sometimes the *very* meaning gets dashes: ever-so-rude.

So typo or not, the editor probably saw it as ever-too-short, which is a strange way of writing *very short*. They thought the sentence was "if this was very short it could cause an electrical fire". That's what I thought (I had to read it twice) -- maybe these special fuses can't be near batteries, so you need a long wire? It's a rare error due to the 2 meanings of *short*. For example, if it said "were ever too short **out**" or "were ever too **have a** short" the to/too typo would be obvious.

Comment: Such an invaluable example, that explains the difference between two different meanings! Thank you so much for your time.